# How can I search through and assign from a collection of C++ derived objects?

Tags: c++, architecture, containers

I got a good answer to the technical part of [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434738/i-cant-assign-from-pointer-to-pointer-to-derived-class-and-pointer-to-pointer-t) as to why my current approach to this is not working (assigning `derived**` to `base**` is type-unsafe, see also [Converting Derived** to Base** and Derived* to Base*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264587/converting-derived-to-base-and-derived-to-base)). However, I still don't have a good idea of how to implement what I'm thinking of in a C++ manner. I'm starting a new question, since the last title was too specific.

Here's perhaps a clearer explanation of what I am trying to do:

1. Create a number of objects which are all instances of classes derived from one single class.
2. Store these objects in some type of master container along with a compile-time human-readable identifier (probably a string?).
3. Get a list of identifiers from other components, search through the master container, and pass them back (pointers/references to) the corresponding objects so they can read/modify them. I think I need to break type-safety at this point and assume that the components know the derived type that they are asking for by identifier.

I thought this would be relatively simple and elegant to do with maps, vectors, and pointers to objects (I give a simplified example in my [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434738/i-cant-assign-from-pointer-to-pointer-to-derived-class-and-pointer-to-pointer-t)), but it seems I'm going to have to be doing a lot of C-style type casting to allow the components to pass pointers to the locations to store the value from the master container. This indicates to me that I'm not following a C++ paradigm, but what "should" I do?

[Edit] Here's some hypothetical sample code for how I envisioned this, hope this clarifies my thinking:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class BaseObj {};
class Der1Obj: public BaseObj {};
class Der2Obj: public BaseObj {};

typedef map<string, BaseObj**> ObjPtrDict;
typedef map<string, BaseObj*> ObjDict;

class BaseComp
{
public:
   ObjPtrDict objs;
};

class DervComp
{
   DervComp(){objs["d1"] = &d1; objs["d2"] = &d2; } // This wouldn't compile
   Der1Obj* d1;
   Der2Obj* d2;
}

typedef vector<BaseComp*> CompList;

void assign_objs(CompList comps, ObjDict objs)
{
   for (auto c = comps.begin(); c != comps.end(); c++)
     for (auto o = c.objs.begin(); o != c.objs.end(); o++)
       *(o->second) = objs[o->first];
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Der1Obj d, d1;
    Der2Obj d2;
    ObjDict objs;
    objs["d"] = &d;
    objs["d1"] = &d1;
    objs["d2"] = &d2;

    DervComp c;
    vector<DervComp*> comps;
    comps.push_back(&c);

    assign_objs(comps, objs);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm with you right up until 3, why does any of that nessesitate having `Base**` objects anywhere and not just `std::map<string, Base*>` (or better yet `std::map<string,std::unique_ptr<Base>>`)?

Comment: It *can* be elegant, but it requires you to step up the abstraction ladder and actually take advantage of polymorphism by basing your code on `Base` pointers. If necessary, make use of the Visitor pattern for type discrimination. It's impossible to give specific advice without specific use cases. Possibly the whole idea of a master container is getting in your way.

Comment: @Collin The components define members Derived1*, Derived2*, etc. to point to the object instances. To fill in the values, I need to pass a list of pointers to these members (i.e. Base**) to the top-level search.

Answer (score 0):

If I got what you want right, you can do it like this:

```
#include <vector>

class Base
{
public:
    enum eDerived
    {
    //name these whatever you like
        DER1,//for first derived class
        DER2,//for second derived class
        DER3//for third derived class
    };

    virtual eDerived type() = 0;//this will return the class type.
};

class Derived1: public Base
{
public:
    virtual eDerived type() { return DER1; }
};

class Derived2: public Base
{
public:
    virtual eDerived type() { return DER2; }
};

class Derived3: public Base
{
public:
    virtual eDerived type() { return DER3; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Base*> myList;//container for all elements
    //You can store a pointer to any of the derived classes here like this:
    Base * a = new Derived1();
    Base * b = new Derived2();
    Base * c = new Derived3();

    myList.push_back(a);
    myList.push_back(b);
    myList.push_back(c);

    //Iterating through the container
    for( Base * tmp: myList)
    {
        //You can check the type of the item like this:
        if( tmp->type() == Base::DER1 )
        {  
            //and cast to a corresponding type.
            //In this case you are sure that you are casting to the right type, since
            //you've already checked it.
            Derived1 * pointerToDerived1 = static_cast<Derived1 *>(tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Ofc you can choose any type of container. If you want to give them an ID, you could either use `map`, or add it into the class itself.

Comment: There's very rarely any good reason to implement your own typeid system, C++ has that built in through `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @Collin, for some reason I thought OP doesn't want to use dynamic_cast, and wants to make sure of the exact derived type before casting. Let's wait for his input on this.

Answer (score 0):

I read your other post, but I think I don´t understand why you would use double pointers. In my understanding you would just use a normal pointer.

E.g.

```
class Base
{
};

class Deriv : public Base
{
};

std::map< std::string, Base* > ObjectStore;

function Component1( ... )
{
   Base* b = ObjectStore[ "MyObject" ];
   b->DoSomeFancyStuff();
}

function ModifyObjectStore( )
{
   delete ObjectStore[ "MyObject" ];
   ObjectStore[ "MyObject" ] = new Derived(); 

}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That is interesting...assigning from the map in the class declaration. What if ObjectStore is not populated until run time?

Answer (score 0):

You says, "pass them back the corresponding object". For this why do you want to pass back the base**? You can simply give back the a map from string to pointer back. Please see the code below for explanation.

```
class Container
{
    void add(const string& aKey_in, Base* b)
    {
        myObjects[aKey_in] = b;
    }
    void getObjs(list<string> aKeys_in, map<string,Base*>& anObjMap_out)
    {
        for(all string s in the aKeys_in)
            anObjMap_out[s] = myObjects[s];
    }
private:
    map<string, base*> myObjects;
};
```

You conditions meet here:
*Create a number of objects which are all instances of classes derived from one single class.*
  You could extend the class to have creation logic, factory logic etc.

*Store these objects in some type of master container along with a compile-time human-readable identifier (probably a string?).*
  Achieved with the map

*Get a list of identifiers from other components, search through the master container, and pass them back (pointers/references to) the corresponding objects so they can read/modify them. I think I need to break type-safety at this point and assume that the components know the derived type that they are asking for by identifier.*

You don't need to pass back the pointer to pointer to the client. Just pass back the object pointers.

Additional note:
You could implement the pointers with shared_ptr instead of raw pointers.
If your client code (whoever is using the getObjs() method) is written properly then you won't need a dynamic cast from base pointer to derived pointer. They should be able to work with the base pointer.
Anyway, that is a different question which you haven't asked yet.

Comment: My verbal description was obviously lacking, so I edited the question to include sample code. The main thing not included in your (quite clear) example is that the "master container" is _outside_ the Component, and the object is a (pointer) member of it. Thus, in my vision, the Component needs to pass out the location of this member (p-to-p) along with the identifier to have an outer process find and fill in the appropriate pointer.