# C++ pointer mechanism - error 2440

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conversion of pointer-to-pointer between derived and base classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532422/conversion-of-pointer-to-pointer-between-derived-and-base-classes)
>   [Converting Derived** to Base** and Derived* to Base*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264587/converting-derived-to-base-and-derived-to-base)

I have an intf + class

```
class IList
{
public:
    virtual IList** GetChildList()=0;
    virtual void SetChildList(IList**)=0;
    ~IList();
};

class CList:public IList
{
    CList** m_lst;
public:
    IList** GetChildList()=0;
    virtual void SetChildList(IList**);
//...
};

IList** CList::GetChildList()
{
    return m_lst;
}
```

Why do I get error 2440 in MSVC in GetChildList saying "'return' : cannot convert from 'CList** **' to 'IList **"

Thanks for the help, in advance!

Answer (score 0):

CList is derived from IList, so you can convert CList* to IList*.  However, you can't convert CList** to IList**.  You need a reinterpret_cast.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way where I can live without reinterpret_cast as it is strictly not advised in a type safe language?