# Why does implicit conversion from non-const to const not happen here?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, implicit-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why isnt it legal to convert (pointer to pointer to non-const) to a (pointer to pointer to a const)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220916/why-isnt-it-legal-to-convert-pointer-to-pointer-to-non-const-to-a-pointer-to)
>   [Double pointer const-correctness warnings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055655/double-pointer-const-correctness-warnings-in-c)

I'm passing a `gchar**` to a [g_key_file_set_string_list](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Key-value-file-parser.html#g-key-file-get-string-list) which expects a `const gchar * const identifier []`

```
/* this function is part of the GLib library */
void g_key_file_set_string_list(GKeyFile *key_file,
                                const gchar *group_name,
                                const gchar *key,
                                const gchar * const list[],
                                gsize length);

const gchar **terms = malloc(sizeof(gchar*) * count);
...
...
g_key_file_set_string_list(<something>, <something>, <something>,
                           terms, count);
```

and GCC 4.7.1 with the options `-std=c99 -pedantic` gives me this

> warning: passing argument 4 of 'g_key_file_set_string_list' from
>   incompatible pointer type
>
> note: expected 'const gchar * const*' but argument is of type 'gchar **'

AFAIK, both in C and C++, conversion to const from non-const is implicit, which is the reason we see standard functions like `strcpy` to take const args. Then doesn't it happen here?

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/constptrptr-conversion.html

Comment: Also, related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264587/converting-derived-to-base-and-derived-to-base/11264741#11264741

Comment: Note that `gchar **` to a `const gchar * const *` is legal in C++, but not in C.

Comment: @JesseGood: That's true, I noticed that in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055655/double-pointer-const-correctness-warnings-in-c without which C++ FAQ 17.18 was only confusiung me @ best.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html is the right FAQ to refer in this case :)